# Listen for SELECT queries on a specific connection

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

How can I get notified when a SELECT query to a specific database is prepared or executed in Spring Boot with Hibernate?

The only thing I really need is the SQL.

In `org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl` I see a call to

```
jdbcCoordinator.getJdbcSessionOwner().getJdbcSessionContext().getObserver().jdbcPrepareStatementStart()
```

which looks like an event but I have no idea how to add a listener for this event or if this event even contains the SQL of the SELECT query.

I can create a custom appender for `org.hibernate.SQL` logger but this way I don't have any information about the connection being used.

Comment: We used our own wrapper for around all Sql interfaces to intercept such calls.

Comment: Can you give an example of such wrapper in an answer or in a Gist?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is [spring-boot-data-source-decorator](https://github.com/gavlyukovskiy/spring-boot-data-source-decorator). It's a Spring Boot starter, that allows you to log all database operations transparently. You will probably need `P6Spy` integration.

```java
@Bean
public JdbcEventListener myListener() {
    return new JdbcEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBeforeExecuteQuery(StatementInformation statementInformation, String sql) {
            // write you business logic here
        }        

        @Override
        public void onAfterExecuteQuery(StatementInformation statementInformation, long timeElapsedNanos, String sql, SQLException e) {
            // write you business logic here
        }
    };
}
```